# Make array from a string of acceptable substrings

Tags: php

I want to take a string and break it down into only acceptable strings such as:

```
$acceptableChars = array("A", "B", "C", "<3");
$enteredWord = "AC<3"
```

And I want the outcome to be

```
$desiredOutcome = array("A","C","<3")
```

The only thing that I keep thinking is str_split() but that cuts into "<" and "3"

Any help will be truly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You'd probably want to create some sort of string tokenizer to read in strings and compare them against the allowed "characters"

Comment: why not just make a list of forbidden words? will probably be more efficient since you have combinations of characters...

Answer (score 0):

You only have one problem. You might be happier with 2.

```
$pattern = '/' . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $acceptableChars)) . '/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $enteredWord, $matches);
$desiredOutcome = $matches[0];
```

This will build a regex from your tokens, find all of them, and put them in `$matches`.